# how to generate 2D map with obsticles but no enclaves?

Tags: procedural-generation

I have a start position and a end position. There needs to be a route from start to end. Obsticles can be anywhere and in anyconfiguration, but all the non obsticle tiles on the grid must be reachable from all non obsticle tiles on the grid.

Currently i generate map fully randomly, this can cause enclaves and that is a problem. red are obsticles

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options here, but the commonly used ones boil down to some version of the following:

1. Use something like the flood-fill algorithm to check whether the map is all connected. If the area that the fill finds is the whole map, the map is connected. If it is connected, then we're done.
2. If it isn't all connected then either roll a new map and go back to step 1. Or try deleting walls and check if it is connected. Possibly the flood fill could track which walls to remove, but removing random walls could also work.